# Do we have to marshall unsigned long?

Tags: c#, mono, unmanaged, managed, primitive-types

The API I am using has something like this:

```
int simpletran(LPSTRUCT req)
{
    printf("%d", req->length);
}

typedef unsigned long ULONG;

typdef struct _st {
  ULONG length;
}STRUCT, *LPSTRUCT;
```

My C# version of it:

```
[DllImport(LINUXLIB, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern simpletran(STRUCT req);

class STRUCT
{
  public UInt32 length;
}
STRUCT st = new STRUCT();
st.length = (UInt32)100;
simpletran(st);
```

When I call the unmanaged function I get some long negative values like -31245665!!!

I am using C# mono on a Linux machine.

Comment: yes I did and doesn't work!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested any of this, so it may need some changes, but here's what I see off hand.

First off, `STRUCT` should be declared as follows:

```
struct STRUCT
{
    public UInt32 length;
}
```

Notice that we changed from `class` to `struct` so that the memory layout of the object is known and matches what the C code is expecting.

**Update**

After a bit of further consideration, there's an easier way of declaring and calling the method, I'll leave the original answer below for another way of doing it.

Your P/Invoke signature should be:

```
[DllImport(LINUXLIB, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int simpletran(ref STRUCT req);
```

Notice that we changed `STRUCT` to `ref STRUCT` since `STRUCT` is a value type and the C code requires a pointer to that structure.

And you'd call it like this:

```
STRUCT st = new STRUCT();
st.length = (UInt32)100;
simpletran(ref st);
```

**Original**

```
[DllImport(LINUXLIB, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int simpletran(IntPtr req);
```

Notice that we changed `STRUCT` to `IntPtr` since `STRUCT` has to be a value type and the C code requires a pointer to that structure.

And you'd call it like this:

```
STRUCT st = new STRUCT();
st.length = (UInt32)100;
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(STRUCT));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(st, ptr, false);
simpletran(ptr);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

Adding the extra steps in between creating the instance and calling the method for allocating a chunk of unmanaged memory to store the value of the struct in ([Marshal.AllocHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx)) and copying the value of `st` into that memory with [Marshal.StructureToPtr(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx). Be sure to free the allocated memory after the call with a call to [Marshal.FreeHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx)

Comment: the reason why i am using class is that class is passed by reference (since it is heap allocated) and struct is passed by value, of course we can use the ref.

Comment: It needs to be a struct as you can't control the memory layout of a class, only structs